# Web browser still actively supported on Windows XP

Tags: web-browser, windows-xp

I have found out that chrome, firefox, ie are not supported on winXP already.

Any web browser that is officially supported on Windows XP?

Comment: I would go with the latest version of chrome/chromium that works.  Disable JavaScript and you'll be okay if you need JavaScript I'm afraid you may out of luck.

Comment: @William Many thanks. I'm using the latest version of chrome, but still isn't supported. How to disable JavaScript?

Comment: I run XP on Linux in a virtual machine it runs great

Comment: XP and Linux are both operating systems. How is one run under the other?

Comment: virtual box is a free software to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kodiologist is certainly very right in cautioning you not to use Windows XP since the OS is not supported and full of big and widely known security holes.

But the question is still valid in the case you are using Windows XP for some reason, let's even say for limited things in a Virtual Machine or so, and at the very least you should still try to be as protected as possible. two wrongs don't make a right...

The only semi-mainstream browser with an option for XP is **Opera**, which has **version 36.0.2130.80** which is supposedly updated with security fixes and supports XP. It can be downloaded here https://ftp.opera.com/pub/opera-winxpvista/36.0.2130.80/win/

Another option is **SeaMonkey**, which is based on an older version of Firefox, and still officially supports Windows XP: https://www.seamonkey-project.org/releases/

Comment: I installed both Opera and SeaMonkey. They don't outrun other browsers that XP doesn't support in performance. I still can't access facebook, instagram, tinder, and youtube videos won't play.

Answer (score -1):

For all but certain embedded versions, Microsoft ceased support for XP in 2014. There are major security issues that have become public knowledge since then and won't be fixed. Trying to release security updates for a web browser for XP is hence futile. So even if there are any web browsers for XP that are still getting updates, using them would get you little more than false hope.